# How to automatically calculate just the current worksheet

Tags: excel-2010, worksheet

I have a workbook with some complicated formulas. One worksheet within the workbook is very slow to calculate. I'm Ok with that because it has a lot of work to do. The problem is that I would like the worksheet to only recalculate when I'm on that worksheet.

The default options provided by Excel only appear to deal with the entire workbook, which affects every workbook. Currently, Excel is set to **Manual - Recalculate workbook before saving**. Opting to save or use SHIFT+F9 every time I make a small update on an unrelated worksheet, is not realistic. The automatic options are too slow.

Does anyone know how to set Excel to just update the current worksheet?
Plan B, does anyone know how to just set the recalculate options for each workbook?

Answer (score 0):

**Shift + F9** to calculate the current worksheet.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to AUTOMATICALLY just do the CURRENT WORKSHEET without doing the entire workbook. I've already stated the manual way in my description.